# Showing a table after rotating by 90 in wx-python

Tags: python, wxpython, dabo

I have to display a table with multiple columns but only a single row. Displaying it in the normal way using wxGrid doesnt look appealing at all and makes it hard for the user to read. I want to know if there is any way in which I can flip the table and display its contents vertically? Also is there any other way to make the data more presentable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just label the rows with the column names and the make one column. Then you could scroll through it that way. You just need to call SetRowLabelValue(rowNum, label). You may find this tutorial helpful (see the end): http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/04/wxpython-grid-tips-and-tricks/

You could use a ListBox, but then you'd lose the label information.